# Huawei U8160 cyanogenmod support?

Tags: cyanogenmod, huawei-u8160

I've seen people have tried cyanogenmod on the Huawei U8150 and someone suggested to give it a try on the Huawei U8160 (Vodafone smart in the UK). What is the level of compatibility I should expect from the Huawei U8160 with cyanogenmod?

http://android.modaco.com/content/other/340961/vodafone-858-smart-huawei-u8160/

Comment: Can you ask more specifically exactly what you're looking for?  A "Yes" is about all this question asks for.  From the [FAQ]: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site "

Comment: ok, edited now to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, I found there is people already working on having cyanogenmod on this model:

https://github.com/sebastian404/android_device_huawei_u8160

Answer (score 2):

There are two places to look for more information on this.  That would be the actual [CyanogenMOD website](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) and the [xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/).  A search of both places shows that there isn't anything readily available for the U8160.  This means that you would need to do a significant amount of hacking to get it working.